# How do I load the second of two cascading combo boxes based on the first combo box selection?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

How do I populate my second combo box based on the first combo box selection?

I am not getting an error, but nothing is loaded in the combo box.

```vb
Private Sub cboSAP_AfterUpdate()

    Me.cboProcess.RowSource = "SELECT ProcessStep FROM" & _
                              " tblProcess WHERE SAPPN = " & Me.cboSAP & _
                              " ORDER BY ProcessStep"
    Me.cboProcess = Me.cboProcess.ItemData(0)

End Sub
```

Link to file:
https://uflorida-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jenn2483_ufl_edu/EYzFG7DEz8RJmgcSl2UltskB1d1ObqN7IKACKIE4pisfzA?e=5AFPSI

Comment: What field type is SAPPN? What is the value of cboSAP? Include semi-colon at end of SQL. SO discourages links to file downloads. Everything needed to evaluate an issue should be within the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". If your link rots, which they do, your question will do little to help others seeking a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cam try:

Me.cboSapp.Value if your Sappnr is in first column, cboSAPP.column(0) when your cboSapp isn’t numeric, then you have to ad single wuotes in the sql,